# Calculations wrong with my delimited layer

Tags: qgis, point, spreadsheet, delimiter

I'm really at my wit's end with using QGIS for marking data points in a delimited layer that just won't show up I need it for a grad paper. It worked previously with another data spreadsheet that I used but I realized it had the wrong variables in them so I had to reinput the right data in a separate sheet and then convert it to CSV.

As far as I can tell, I did everything right by making sure the input box is correct. Right down to putting longitude and latitude. But no matter how hard I try I cant get it right. For Reference, I'm also linking the sheets that did work (labeled School Address) and those that didn't (labeled otherwise)

Am I missing something?

[image: my panel]

[image: What shows up]
[image: What works]
[image: another example]
[image: What hasnt worked]

Comment: Latitude: 990141, Longitude: 202349? Those are not degree units.

Comment: That's what I got from the data set

Comment: Your working spreadsheets are using latitude and longitude (degree coordinates). Your not-working spreadsheet is not using latitude and longitude. It's using X, Y coordinates in a projected coordinate system. You need to find out what projected coordinate system those coordinates are in and tell QGIS that.

Answer (score 4):

You got the wrong columns out of the excel file.

I assume you got the file from here:
http://council.nyc.gov/public-advocate/wp-content/uploads/sites/74/2019/01/school_explorer_data_final.xlsx

and that you used the `X Coordinate` and `Y Coordinate` columns.
You should use the `Lat` and `Lon` column instead:

[image]

Since you seem to be quite new on the QGIS block, here is also a welcome gift in the form of a...

## Step-by-step:

1. Export the columns you need in csv (including `Lat` and `Lon`)
2. in QGIS import the csv file as `Delimited Text`, making sure you use the coordinates as intended:

[image]

3. result

[image]